# Why is my ethernet connection connecting and disconnecting repeatedly?

Tags: 11.10, networking

Just trying to get my ethernet connection to work in Oneiric, and when I plug the cable in it connects and disconnects forever.  /var/syslog says this (repeats it over and over again):

```
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Activation (eth0) successful, device activated.
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) complete.
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Get) complete.
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <warn> dnsmasq exited with error: Network access problem (address in use; permissions; etc) (2)
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> (eth0): device state change: activated -> failed (reason 'sharing-start-failed') [100 120 18]
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <warn> Activation (eth0) failed.
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> (eth0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R avahi-daemon[1321]: Withdrawing address record for 10.42.43.1 on eth0.
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R avahi-daemon[1321]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 10.42.43.1.
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R avahi-daemon[1321]: Interface eth0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Clearing nscd hosts cache.
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table nat --delete POSTROUTING --source 10.42.43.0/255.255.255.0 ! --destination 10.42.43.0/255.255.255.0 --jump MASQUERADE
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --delete FORWARD --destination 10.42.43.0/255.255.255.0 --out-interface eth0 --match state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED --jump ACCEPT
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --delete FORWARD --source 10.42.43.0/255.255.255.0 --in-interface eth0 --jump ACCEPT
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --delete FORWARD --in-interface eth0 --out-interface eth0 --jump ACCEPT
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --delete FORWARD --out-interface eth0 --jump REJECT
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --delete FORWARD --in-interface eth0 --jump REJECT
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R ntpdate[15004]: Can't find host ntp.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known (-2)
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R ntpdate[15004]: no servers can be used, exiting
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --delete INPUT --in-interface eth0 --protocol udp --destination-port 67 --jump ACCEPT
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --delete INPUT --in-interface eth0 --protocol tcp --destination-port 67 --jump ACCEPT
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --delete INPUT --in-interface eth0 --protocol udp --destination-port 53 --jump ACCEPT
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --delete INPUT --in-interface eth0 --protocol tcp --destination-port 53 --jump ACCEPT
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R avahi-daemon[1321]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::a800:4ff:fe00:a04.
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R avahi-daemon[1321]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Sep 26 17:06:47 X58A-UD3R avahi-daemon[1321]: Registering new address record for fe80::a800:4ff:fe00:a04 on eth0.*.
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'Wired'.
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Activation (eth0) starting connection 'Wired'
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> (eth0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> (eth0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> (eth0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Get) scheduled...
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R avahi-daemon[1321]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::a800:4ff:fe00:a04 on eth0.
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R avahi-daemon[1321]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::a800:4ff:fe00:a04.
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R avahi-daemon[1321]: Interface eth0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Get) started...
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) started...
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R avahi-daemon[1321]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 10.42.43.1.
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R avahi-daemon[1321]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R avahi-daemon[1321]: Registering new address record for 10.42.43.1 on eth0.IPv4.
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> caught signal 15, shutting down normally.
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Clearing nscd hosts cache.
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --insert INPUT --in-interface eth0 --protocol tcp --destination-port 53 --jump ACCEPT
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --insert INPUT --in-interface eth0 --protocol udp --destination-port 53 --jump ACCEPT
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --insert INPUT --in-interface eth0 --protocol tcp --destination-port 67 --jump ACCEPT
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --insert INPUT --in-interface eth0 --protocol udp --destination-port 67 --jump ACCEPT
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --insert FORWARD --in-interface eth0 --jump REJECT
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --insert FORWARD --out-interface eth0 --jump REJECT
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --insert FORWARD --in-interface eth0 --out-interface eth0 --jump ACCEPT
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --insert FORWARD --source 10.42.43.0/255.255.255.0 --in-interface eth0 --jump ACCEPT
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --insert FORWARD --destination 10.42.43.0/255.255.255.0 --out-interface eth0 --match state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED --jump ACCEPT
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Executing: /sbin/iptables --table nat --insert POSTROUTING --source 10.42.43.0/255.255.255.0 ! --destination 10.42.43.0/255.255.255.0 --jump MASQUERADE
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> Starting dnsmasq...
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R NetworkManager[1344]: <info> (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> activated (reason 'none') [70 100 0]
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R dnsmasq[15064]: failed to create listening socket for 10.42.43.1: Address already in use
Sep 26 17:06:50 X58A-UD3R dnsmasq[15064]: FAILED to start up
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

correct me if im wrong but it looks like you are trying to use a shared connection. There is a bug in oneiric regarding this. Please look at a different answer for a workaround and the link to the bug.
[Wired Connection shared with other computers connects then disconnects in the nm-applet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64494/wired-connection-shared-with-other-computers-connects-then-disconnects-in-11-10-n)
The workaround is to set IPv6 to ignore when you edit the connection and then do sudo killall dnsmasq

Comment: I did this too. But not resolved here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/148055/ubuntu-11-10-everytime-i-am-trying-to-connect-to-my-box-using-ssh-its-failing

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happens when I try to serve ad hoc wireless Internet sharing on Ubuntu11.10
`sudo killall dnsmasq` has helped finally.

Comment: It did not helped in my case here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/148055/ubuntu-11-10-everytime-i-am-trying-to-connect-to-my-box-using-ssh-its-failing

Answer (score 0):

Diagnose the driver by clicking the LAN icon, open Network Sharing, click on Local Area Connections, Diagnose.

It fixed for me. This will reset the LAN adapter, so it will function normally.

Comment: This answer would be even better, if you could add a screenshot.