# Wired Connection shared with other computers connects then disconnects in the nm-applet

Tags: network-manager

connecting with shared with other computers connection in NetworkManager. Other computer gets IP but NetworkManager disconnects the shared connection after half a second.
This same setup worked perfectly fine in 11.04. Is there any fix, workaround or alternative way to share a connection with another computer over an Ethernet cable. (I can downgrade to 11.04 but I'd rather not ).

EDIT: found a workaround
The workaround for now is to set IPv6 options to Ignore and then sudo killall dnsmasq. Reconnect and it should work.

Comment: Can you post the fix as an answer?

Comment: Bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/865001

Answer (score 7):

**It is not fixed yet**. I have had this issue just now and the workarround mentioned by the OP did the trick.

> The workaround for now is to set IPv6 options to Ignore and then `sudo killall dnsmasq`. Reconnect and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

This article seems to address the issue.  Appears that dnsmasq should be removed.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a bug and it's supposed to have been fixed. I haven't had the time to test it myself yet, but you might want to. This site is for questions and answers. Bugs are handled on Launchpad.net. Here's a direct link to the bug you're after: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/865001. Please describe details about your situation and hopefully it'll get fixed before release.

That bug thread has a workaround that is supposed to work, but as I said, I haven't had the time to test it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but discovered that I had a regular network patch cable connecting my Netbook to my HD Home Run.  I replaced it with a crossover cable and the intermittent connect/disconnect messages went away.

Answer (score 1):

I had to `sudo killall dnsmasq` first so I could click the config box then set ipv6 to ignore then `sudo killall dnsmasq` again...taken me about 4 hours to get connection sharing to work (just dumped Windows).