# Internet Connection Sharing connect/disconnect loop

Tags: networking

I am trying to share my Ubuntu 11.10 internet connection via my wireless to another computer via ethernet. When I try to share them I get this endless "Connection Established"/"Disconnected" loop. I've tried updating everything, tried using Firestarter, tried everything I knew to. The card is supported for this because I was able to do it back in 11.04. Any help would be nice. :)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same but yet can't find an answer. Hope you receive one.

Comment: See this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64494/wired-connection-shared-with-other-computers-connects-then-disconnects-in-11-10

Answer (score 4):

here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/865001
it is recommended to set IPv6 to "Ignore" and `sudo killall dnsmasq`

worked for me

Comment: Not working for me. With the wired connections I have done the IPv6 stuff and dnsmasq and still if I so much as think about sharing with the wired cards it starts the endless loop.

Comment: Worked for me too: with Ubuntu 11.10 and 10.04, but I had to unplugg the ethernet cable, then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

ICS seems to work perfectly despite the messages.

Killing the `nm-applet` from the System Monitor got rid of the messages and ICS was still working OK.

**Solution:**

Go to the IPv6 Settings tab for the ICS connection, *set the method* to **Ignore** and *uncheck* the **Require IPv6....** box.

Comment: Solved - go to the IPv6 Settings tab for the ICS connection, set the method to ignore and uncheck the 'Require IPv6....' box.