# Sharing internet (wireless broadband usb) with router

Tags: internet, sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I share a wireless internet connection via Ethernet with an Xbox 360?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90595/how-do-i-share-a-wireless-internet-connection-via-ethernet-with-an-xbox-360)

how do i share my Internet with a router? is it as simple as going into network manager and selecting the appropriate connection to the router and selecting "share with other computers" under ipv4 settings?

im trying to connect my xbox to the router and the connection just connects and disconnects every 2 seconds indefinitely.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It should be as easy as that, yes. You may want to deactivate IPv6. There's been some issues with that. I don't know if it's fixed. The symptoms of that problem is frequent connect/disconnects.

Comment: Has anyone actualy tried this and had it working? Because i just cant get it working. Is there something on the router i need to configure? Like ips and dns stuff?

Comment: There shouldn't be anything special about a router. If you have a laptop or something, try with it. If that doesn't work, then something is wrong. If it does work, then you have to troubleshoot the router. When you share an internet connection with Ubuntu, it will setup DHCP, meaning that the other computer will get a random IP. The router must be configured to obtain an IP from a DHCP server.