# make my laptop a wifi router

Tags: 11.10, wireless

I use an application called [connectify](http://connectify.me/) to turn my laptop to a wifi router and provide other devices with internet using my DSL connection. But after I switched to Ubuntu 11.10 I can't use this any more. Is there any Linux software or trick available to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, Ubuntu and many of it's flavors have feature called "ad-hoc network"
and "wifi tethering"

To make wifie hotspot, you need to have some connection (cable connection, or another wifi connection (that woudl require a second wifi adapter).

Remember, you can't use the same adapter as WiFi receiver and wifi spot.

Go to network settings -> `Edit Connections` -> `Wireless` -> `Add`.
Create a new connection and select `Ad-hoc` in `Mode` you can specify a password and enjoy.

Comment: last time I did, was not really fast though, but acceptable for browsing.

Comment: Are these instructions complete?  Don't you need to enable sharing as well?

Comment: @MariusGedminas no you don't need.Ad-hoc means sharing

Comment: You mean Network Manager automatically enables IP forwarding and sets up NAT as soon as you create an Ad-hoc connection?  I didn't know that.  (I'm not sure I believe it, either ;)

Comment: @MariusGedminas yes! I worked like that already. I didn't set any routing, NAT or any forwarding, masquerades.

Comment: In newer Ubuntu (14.04) it's `...->Add->Wireless(Shared)` which creates a "connection" in mode "Access Point".

Answer (score 3):

there is bug currently in Ubuntu so there is [work around](https://askubuntu.com/q/64494/52590) for making ad hoc wifi access point, queting bellow:

"connecting with shared with other computers connection in NetworkManager. Other computer gets IP but NetworkManager disconnects the shared connection after half a second. This same setup worked perfectly fine in 11.04. Is there any fix, workaround or alternative way to share a connection with another computer over an Ethernet cable. (I can downgrade to 11.04 but I'd rather not ).

EDIT: found a workaround The workaround for now is to set IPv6 options to Ignore and then sudo killall dnsmasq. Reconnect and it should work."

I done it on my laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 and mine working fine now.