# Share wifi. Ubuntu PC needs to share Widows 7 wifi to access internet

Tags: networking

I have not found this exact question ( I think, or I just don't get it ).
**

- Goal: Get my Ubuntu PC on the internet.

**
**

- Problem: No direct network access at all on Ubuntu.

**
**

- Set-up:

**

1. Ubuntu 13.10 PC is directly connected via ethernet cable to Windows
   7 PC.
2. Windows 7 has shared internet connection option activated.
3. Windows 7 has 2 network connections: wifi to gateway/network and
   local one to Ubuntu PC - both labeled with 'internet access'.
4. Ubuntu connection has no internet access.  Only connected to Windows
   PC locally.

Not sure of my vocabulary here.  Please speak newbie, or know-nothing-bie.
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 13.10 - Share wireless internet connection through Ethernet](http://askubuntu.com/questions/359856/ubuntu-13-10-share-wireless-internet-connection-through-ethernet)

Comment: @Rmano, I think this is a different question, that answer applies to Ubuntu sharing an internet connection with another computer, I think the OP is asking here to get Ubuntu to use Windows shared internet, not share his Ubuntu connection with Windows(I think??)

Comment: @TrailRider Hmmm... maybe you're right. Probably the Ubuntu side of the configuration is the same, too; it's just the matter to devise how to set up the windows side. No idea about windows... Maybe better asked on SuperUser?

Comment: @Rmano as it involves Windows interacting with Ubuntu, it should be on topic here so the OP just needs to get help from someone who still uses Windows and can give instruction(I quit using Windows after I tried 11.04 and was still using XP so I have no idea about Windows 7 either...)

Comment: Yes --- I agree. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Maybe if you add the Windows interfaces configuration (like these: http://imgur.com/uIk9tWD ) for the two windows interfaces (wired and wireless), and the configuration for the Linux one (network applet -> network connections -> choose wired -> options -> ipv4 tab) someone could guess an answer...

Comment: This *might* be a Windows issue rather than an Ubuntu issue, but let's see: I recommend editing this to include the output of `ifconfig` in Ubuntu. (Feel free to [sanitize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanitization_(classified_information)) [MAC addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_address) by replacing them with * characters or whatnot; as for IP addresses, if they're LAN IP's (usually 192.168...) they're usually not sensitive.) I think more info on the Windows settings is needed too, to show if the problem is with Ubuntu or Windows. (Maybe a screenshot?)

Comment: Okay. I am a simpleton. What screen shots would be helpful?

Comment: The connection I have between Ubuntu and Windows is wired directly and okay. The Windows says that connection has internet connection. And I have the Windows wireless connection to the internet too. The Ubuntu is connected to Windows machine - according to Ubuntu the connection works - but no internet. Just a connection to the Windows machine.

Comment: **I agree in that is a Windows7 issue. It cannot seem to handle this. settings are changing on their own, and other crap.**
 
**Solution**: I have an ancient docked wireless laptop that I will use again.  Gotta go buy a power supply - so lame! It has Windows XP (and Xubuntu) and connected easily to give Ubuntu machine internet access. 

I tried to be modern - forget it. I have been using Ubuntu since v.7...and hate Windows more each year.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a software called "connectify" on your windows PC to create a WiFi hot spot that your computer running Ubuntu can connect to...

Comment: My Ubuntu PC does not have wireless capability.  (The PC Card is not working with Ubuntu.)