# Creating bridge from wlan to ethernet

Tags: wireless, ethernet, network-bridge

I know there is lot of threads about bridges and how to make them and manage them but still i haven't reached a goal.

So i need bridge between wlan and ethernet but mean while i need connect to hotspot adapter which will gain access to internet .

so basicaly scheme ir something like this

TP-LINK_M5(hotspot)<---coneection--->pc(wlan adapter)<---bridge--->pc(eth)<--cable-->voip adapter

I haven't tried with windows does it even works. Before that i tried with another tp-link router which had WDS but  network died quite fast.

I know i can reach goal using packet forwarding but i am interested in this option...

Both my cards.

```
  *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 05
   serial: 24:b6:fd:13:b2:bd
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:52 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f3204000-f3204fff memory:f3200000-f3203fff


*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 34
       serial: ac:72:89:35:77:08
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.0.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:54 memory:f7a00000-f7a01fff
```

Comment: Do you really need bridge? - [Bridging Wifi to Ethernet on Ubuntu not working](http://superuser.com/q/597834) or you can share the wlan connection (MASQUERADE ) through wi-fi [Ubuntu 13.10 - Share wireless internet connection through Ethernet](http://askubuntu.com/q/359856)

Comment: Well it would look nice that all is under one network like 192.168.0.0 but thats not significant. I tried share but there is issue. i can ping from router which ar located in ethernet side but from hotspot side i can't ping ethernet network  and internet is not working in ethernet side. And i looked in hotspot  options i can't set ip forward or anything similar to it.