# How to securely share my internet connection with another machine

Tags: networking, internet, sharing, connection-sharing

Right so this is my situation here, I have a router, and several machines, but now there is a new machine which needs to connect to the network at the same time as them. My router is not a Wireless one so only Ethernet connections are available. And to connect the new machine to the network, one of the other machines needs to be disconnected as there just aren't enough ports in the router to plug the cables into.

So I was wondering if there is any way to do some sort of internet sharing so that I connect the machine to my machine and it shares some of my internet? Although I want it to be a direct tunnel to the router, and just using my machine as a relay, so that if the machine gets infected with something it can't do anything to me computer which it will be connecting through.

Both my machine and the new machine are running Ubuntu 15.04.

Both machines also posses wireless capabilities, so would it be possible, if using only wires is harder, to connect our machines together through a wireless connection, and then use my Ethernet connection for the actual internet connection?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can be done (although I don't know exactly how), but keep in mind that you will need an additional network card and that, in order for the new PC to have network access, you'll need to keep the old PC constantly on. It's probably cheaper and easier to just by a network switch.

Comment: @Davide: I remember doing this in the past with another machine when mine did not have wireless capabilities, theirs did, and the router would only accept a wireless connection. And I don't seem to remember us needing anything but an Ethernet cable, and they did not have an additional network card (that I know of). I seem to also remember that they were using Fedora, and I at the time probably Ubuntu 14.10, and that they were simply just using software which was installed (probably as default) on their Fedora installation to get this working.

Comment: I'm sorry. What I meant to say is that you'll need 2 network cards. If the PC with network access is a laptop, it probably has 2 already, one with cable and one wireless. Also, here's a [related question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/359856/share-wireless-internet-connection-through-ethernet)

Comment: You could purchase an Ethernet Switch for very cheap and would be a more rugged and durable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click System Settings >> Network >>  Wireless network >> Use as Hotspot.

This is assuming your hardwired into internet and will broadcast WIFI to the second computer, which of course will suffer performance hits, as will you, but for web browsing, should be fine, just don't try to stream NetFlix!

This is a link to original post I found on subject. [howtogeek](http://bfy.tw/pd7)

Comment: And could I password protect it and all that so that only that certain device could connect to it? And even better if I could also specify the only MAC address which is allowed to use the hotspot?

Comment: I think it auto sets up SSID and PWD