# How do I establish 'wireless internet connection sharing' via ethernet to Raspberry pi

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, raspberrypi

I have searched this subject in great detail and still not able to connect my raspberry pi to the web via Ethernet.

I have no problems making ssh contacts with the pi.

I used this video as a start 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZK-JHfJqmkY

Its Not working.

I'm running ubuntu 15.10 
So how do I get my pi connected to the web using Ethernet from my computer?

Answer (score 0):

This question sounds almost identical: [Share wireless Internet connection through ethernet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359856/share-wireless-internet-connection-through-ethernet)

Here's whatchya gotta do: (thanks [@SuperMau](https://askubuntu.com/users/92840/supermau)):

**In the server computer:**

**1.** On the computer connected to the Internet, click the network icon in the panel and go to *"Edit Connections..."* at the bottom of the menu.

[image]

**2.** Double click your **Wired Connection** (Leave your wireless connection untouched, the one connected to Internet and the one you want to share, as I understand)

[image]

**3.** In the *"IPv4 Settings tab"*, select Method: *"Shared to other computers"*

[image]

**4.** Reconnect clicking on the *Wired Network* so it gets its new IP address. (The two computers must be connected by an ethernet cable for this step, so connect them now if you have not already.)

**5.** Click on *"Connection Information"* in the network menu and write down the IP address and network mask (in my case it was assigned 10.42.0.1/255.255.255.0 but I do not know if that will always be the case)

[image]

**In the client computer:**

**6.** Go to "Edit Connections..." and assign a "Manual" Method. Assign an IP assress in the same subnetwork (10.42.0.69 for example) and put the IP and network mask you wrote down in "Netmask" "Gateway" and "DNS servers"

[image]

**7.** Reconnect to the network to let the new settings be assigned.

**8.** Pat yourself in the back and surf away!!!

Comment: Ok How would I set up this Manual Method for the Raspberry pi? It Doesn't have the same set up like most computers

Comment: Once you know what IP your Ubuntu host has on that ethernet port, simply set the Pi's IP to that same IP, but with a different last segment.  i.e. if Ubuntu has 10.0.53.23 then the Pi needs 10.0.53.x

Answer (score 0):

OK I figure it out. It was simple what was I missing is the how to configure the Raspberry Pi eth0 settings.

Here's what I done.. I did all of steps  1-5 as shown before now I went on to the pi (client side) and typed in

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Then I edited that file to look like this.

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static

address 10.42.0.77

gateway 192.168.1.1

netmask 255.255.255.0

network 10.42.0.1

broadcast 10.42.0.255

dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1

Pretty simple. I took the information from my wifi connection and the new Ethernet connection, and plug in the numbers. I'm glad that I came here because you guys pointed me into the right direction. Thanks