# Share Wifi over Ethernet with PS3

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, ethernet, sharing

Currently I share the Wifi on my laptop to my PS3 over ethernet due to PS3 weak wifi.

In Windows 8.1 all is running smooth. I open the Yotube app on my PS3 and I get full HD.

[I tried to do the same in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359856/share-wireless-internet-connection-through-ethernet) 12.04 and now on 16.04 and I get issues.

The vídeo on Youtube app on the PS3 works for 2 seconds. Stops to load. Changes quality to SD or lower. Many times the conection goes out and the app stops reproducing.

The thing is, I can watch Full HD vídeos on the laptop. I have no Wifi reception issues on the laptop. For some reason, the sharing of internet via cable on Ubuntu does not provide speed or stability.

I also tried the Lan drivers from the manofacturer with no sucess. I don’t know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to establish an Ethernet connection for a Raspberry Pi (and an Xbox 360, which is more similar to your situation, I suppose).

I've got a script on Github here which will do the job: https://github.com/le1ca/rpi-router/blob/master/rpi-router.sh

There are a few things you need to know in advance for this script to work:

- The name of your ethernet interface (obtain this using `ifconfig`).
- The name of your WiFi interface (same deal).
- A static subnet for your ethernet network (this is something you can set up using the instructions on the answer you already linked to).

My script sets up NAT (which is kind of like what your WiFi router does to "hide" your local network from the public Internet) so it will behave slightly differently from a true bridged connection. Sometimes this is necessary, if you are on a very picky WiFi network for example.

To get everything working, just do the initial setup for the static IPs, set the configuration in the first few lines of the script, then run it like `sudo rpi-router.sh`.