# Sharing internet connection between two machines via LAN cable

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, lan, sharing

I got into situation where I catch horrible Wi-Fi signal in my room - basically very slow and unstable connection. However, in other room, signal is strong and connection is stable.

I am thinking about putting my old laptop into room with strong signal, run Lubuntu on it, connect to Wi-Fi and then share connection to my main PC (running Ubuntu) via ethernet cable.

Will I need any special packages or system configuration to do this? I don't want (or need) these computers to be connected on file sharing basis, only thing I want is to have internet connection on my main PC. After measurement, I know I'll need ~20m cable. I'm considering buying it from eBay for low price. Can shoddy cable cause significant packet loss? Should I rather buy more expensive one from local shop with no risk of getting defective piece?

Comment: Instead of spending your money on cat5 cable, and the time to configure your laptop to share your wifi through the ethernet interface, I would recommend you invest in a wireless repeater. They're only $20 - $30, and it's going to solve your problem a lot better than trying to ad hoc something like this. 20m of cable will probably cost you $20 anyway, unless you make the patch cable yourself.

Comment: @hamiheim That could be better solution, but I have no direct access to Wi-Fi, so using ethernet is only solution for me. I also found 30m cat5 cable for 4$ at local shop, and since it's not that much, I'm gonna try it and I hope it will work well (based on reviews, that cable is pretty good despite the low price).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share wireless Internet connection through ethernet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359856/share-wireless-internet-connection-through-ethernet)