# Whilst internet sharing over ethernet client PC cannot connect to internet

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, connection-sharing

I am trying to setup ICS on my Ubuntu machine which is connected to the internet via Wi-Fi and is set to share via ethernet. The client PC uses windows 10.

I followed the very top section of [this help.ubuntu.com guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing) hoping it would be enough to connect two machines together.

In order to get the two devices to talk to each other i gave the host machine `192.168.1.1` and the client machine `192.168.1.2`. (`mask /24, gateway 192.168.1.1`) as seen in [Share wireless Internet connection through ethernet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359856/share-wireless-internet-connection-through-ethernet). My router uses the `192.168.0.x` address range so my manual assignment should not conflict AFAIK.

The two devices can ping each other perfectly fine now. Without this the client PC could not even detect a network (perhaps I don't have DHCP being served from Ubuntu but I don't know how to set that up).

However, the client PC still can't reach the Internet and I don't know what I've done wrong.

What should I do?

Comment: Since your router is probably at 192.168.1.1, you can't use that same address for the host machine.

Comment: My router uses the 192.168.0.x address range. I updated my question

Comment: I believe that you've got to have your PC's on the same subnet as your router. Change their addresses to 192.168.0.x numbers. You may also have to set up routing tables in each PC.

Comment: I set the two devices to use the 192.168.0.x range and it caused the client to no longer be able to connect to the network. I was hoping i wouldnt have to setup specific routing rules since connection sharing in windows works so easily.

Comment: Are you sure that the static addresses that you set don't overlap an existing, all ready in-use, address, like from the DHCP pool? You may have to reboot everything for it to work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10, in order to better spy on and gather information secretly on it's users, employs a non-standard Proxy setup, and after the "Creator's Update" (that will trash your privacy settings, activation, and apps unless you turn all the "phone home" settings, camera, and mic back on) will not allow connection through a "screen" or "firewall" like a Linux box that could block, or track the snooping.  If you have dual-boot to Ubuntu 16.04, or newer, and boot into Ubuntu you will find your connection is just fine once you make the required IP and DNS adjustments.  You will need to read 50-200 pages, depending on your expertise level, to understand how to get clear communication between Win10 and the Net through a Linux box.  It's just not worth the trouble because the next Win10 update should "fix" this "feature".

Easiest solution: Find the article on the Ubuntu website detailing the step by step resizing of the Win10 partition and install Ubuntu for dual boot.  Use an ext3 or ext4 FS so Win10 can't trash your Linux installation - it's widely reported. Boot into Ubuntu (turn on machine, press ESC, press F9(on an HP computer) for the OS menu, select the Ubuntu boot option, press Enter).  Mount the Windows partition using any file manager like Caja, Nemo, etc.  You now have access to all your Windows files AND CAN CHANGE ANYTHING - BE CAREFUL!  Now you can transmit and receive any files you like to and from your Windows partition.  Make a special directory for this to make your life easier.

BTW, AT&T ships most new devices with the default network you have selected, choose a network mask with some other number than "1".  I would use anything from 40-245 myself.  Much harder for hackers to guess.

Hope this helps.

fudoki

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesnt really contribute anything to my question. I know how setup an operating system but this machine needs to stay windows