# Share wireless Internet connection through Ethernet on 18.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, ethernet, sharing

I've in the past successfully set sharing of wireless Internet connection through Ethernet on Ubuntu 16.04 as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359856/share-wireless-internet-connection-through-ethernet). Unfortunately due to disk failure I install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and cannot find anything similar to what is described in mentioned post. All menus are now different and I don't know where to look.

Answer (score 11):

Follows these steps:

1. Open `nm-connection-editor` from the terminal

   ```
   nm-connection-editor
   ```
2. Click on the wired connection and select edit cog wheel below

   [image]
3. Go to the ipv4 settings tab there in the Method select `Shared to Other Computers`

   [image]

Source:

https://www.crookm.com/journal/2018/sharing-wifi-connection-over-ethernet/

Comment: Do you also need to install dnsmasq as a dhcp server for the ethernet client?

Comment: Not according to this article https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

Comment: Your link... under **Advanced Gateway Configuration**... re:dnsmasq...

Advanced configurations include DHCP server and DNS server. A DHCP server allows the client to get an IP address automatically without having to manually configure a static IP. A DNS server allows the client to resolve Internet host names without manually configuring DNS addresses.

Comment: Keep in mind, that with dnsmasq AND systemd-resolved installed at the SAME time, adjustments need to be made on systemd-resolved so it can co-exist nicely.

Comment: I know what a DHCP server and what a DNS server do but I don't see the usefulness of setting up both just to share my internet with another computer!

Comment: Sorry, the earlier comment was just text copied directly out of your link... Didn't mean to offend. Anyway... either it's setup static IP/DNS addresses on the client... and hope they don't conflict with existing IP/DNS addresses already in use... or use something like dnsmasq to assign IP/DNS addresses.

Comment: The other computer is a machine trying to install Windows 10, and after this change it says "Unidentified network - No internet".

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to do this in a terminal environment.

The main reason being nm-connection-editor will not open on manjaro running on a pinephone.

After much looking and words with Jesus, I was given:
https://fedoramagazine.org/internet-connection-sharing-networkmanager/

Which for my needs of sharing over "eth0" produced:

"nmcli connection add type ethernet ifname eth0 ipv4.method shared con-name local"

Since my desktop was already configuring for what I can only guess is some sort of ubuntu-ish default for this sort of thing, the wireless connection was shared and I immediately gained internet connectivity on my desktop.

IPv4 10.42.0.142
subnetmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.42.0.1

This information can of course be found on the device sharing the connection with:
"ip address show"
then look for the interface you are sharing, in my case it is "6: eth0". The gateway information was 2-3 lines below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with no client config:

Assumptions:

- wlan0 is the wifi you want to share to a computer connected via
  ethernet
- eth0 is the ethernet adapter that the client computer is
  connected to
- you have dnsmasq installed via `sudo apt install dnsmasq` for now stop the service with `systemctl stop dnsmasq`

1. Start with assigning an ip to the ethernet, do not use networkmanager GUI as this creates a conflict in dnsmasq `sudo ip addr add 10.42.0.1/24 dev eth0`
2. First `sudo nano /etc/dnsmasq.conf` then add
   `interface=eth0 dhcp-range=10.42.0.50,10.42.0.100,12h server=8.8.8.8 bind-interfaces domain-needed bogus-priv no-dhcp-interface=wlan0`
3. Then start dnsmasq `systemctl start dnsmasq`
4. Open `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf` and uncomment the line `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
5. Finally `sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"`
6. [iptables from here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing) `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o wlan0 -i eth0 -s 10.42.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT`
   `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`
   `sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING`
   `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE`
   `
7. Save `sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables.sav`
8. edit or create /etc/rc.local and add `iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.sav` before exit0
9. run `sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.sav` and make sure there are no errors
10. you should have an established connection with internet working on the client

Comment: How does this differ from the answer already given?