# Sharing Wifi To Ethernet Problem

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, ethernet, dhcp

I'm trying to share my wifi connection from a lubuntu 18.04 machine over Ethernet, where the The Ethernet cable is then plugged in to a switch where I can connect other computers and devices for testing and dev--I've been using this setup for a while sharing the wifi connection from a Windows laptop or from my MacBook Pro.

Should be straightforward, everything I see has these instructions:

> https://www.cesariogarcia.com/?p=611
>
> [Share wireless Internet connection through ethernet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359856/share-wireless-internet-connection-through-ethernet)

and so on. However, when I do this, I get the "Ethernet disconnected" message constantly, which is only resolved if I change the IPv6 method to "Shared to other computers" as well as IPv4, and change `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` from `managed=false` to `managed=true` below the `[ifupdown]` line.

> ***Edit:*** it appears that `managed=true` contributed to breaking all wifi connections, so I've switched it back so I can get at least some internet.

At this point, I can see the Ethernet connection and the Wifi connection, but if I connect any other computer to the network switch, that computer completes DHCP assignment but can't access the internet or even ping the ubuntu machine.

At the moment, this is the IP DHCP assigned to my Ubuntu machine:

> IP: `10.42.0.1`
>
> Subnet Mask: `255.255.255.0`

And if I connect another computer using DHCP (in this case macbook pro) it gets assigned this address:

> IP: `169.245.58.13`
>
> Subnet Mask: `255.255.0.0`

Is it wrong for these addresses to be on different subnets with different subnet masks? Setting the IP addresses and subnet masks manually does not fix the issue.

When I run wireshark on the Ubuntu computer over the ethernet adaptor, I see the DHCP negotiation but nothing after that, I.E. when I ping anything from the macbook I don't see any messages in WireShark.

Everything I'm seeing seems like this should be straightforward and automatic, and I've had it working sharing from Windows and OS X, but I'm completely lost troubleshooting it on Ubuntu.

Does anyone have any additional suggestions I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a satisfying answer, but this problem appears to be resolved by upgrading to 19.10 Eoan Ermine—the network settings all now work as expected.