# I want to share my ethernet connection to wifi

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, ethernet

I'm connected in my computer by ethernet connection (cable) and i want to share this connection so i can use it to connect my phone ( like tranforming cable connection to wifi )

please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sharing Wifi To Ethernet Problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183051/sharing-wifi-to-ethernet-problem)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup an Access Point mode Wi-Fi Hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot)

Answer (score 0):

.You should have an "Wireless card" for make your "cable internet" into a something like a router i think.

.An easy option is connect your phone to your pc with usb and then look in your phone for "usb modem". It allows yo to use your computer internet on you phone(but you will nedd stay near it with this method).

If you dont have a wifi card i think that you could use a second phone and do as i said for usb modem, and then connect with the 1st phone to the wifi made in the 2nd phone(you need to switch to on "share connection" on the phone connected to the pc)

PD: Just in case that someone need to make the inverse process, look at [this](https://www.cesariogarcia.com/?p=611)