# can I share my laptop's internet access with another PC through Lan cable?

Tags: wireless, internet, ethernet, lan, wifi-direct

I am in a rather limited situation that is my house only has Wifi and no Lan(Ethernet) socket on any wall. And, I have a PC that does not have any Wifi adapter and only has usb or Lan sockets.

I can buy a usb-wifi adapter and connect this PC to internet with it but the delivery takes sometime and I need to connect to internet with this PC urgently.

can I share my other laptop's internet access with this PC through a lan cable or any other way? Both use Ubuntu, My laptop also has windows.

---

Edit:

[This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359856/share-wireless-internet-connection-through-ethernet) mentions a method but I don't find the same settings in my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share wireless Internet connection through ethernet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359856/share-wireless-internet-connection-through-ethernet)

Comment: @pLumo I am not finding the same settings in my own Ubuntu 18.04.4 yet. Clicking on the network Icon brings something else.