# Everytime i am trying to connect to my box using SSH, its failing not connecting

Tags: 11.10, networking, ssh, openssh

From any other PC doing SSH to my Ubuntu 11.10,is failing.

**My network setup:**

Telenet ISP (Belgium) > Fiber cable <[image] > RJ45 cable straight > to Ubuntu PC

**Even the SSH is running:**

[image]

**Other PC: retrying over and over**

```
$ ping 192.168.0.128
PING 192.168.0.128 (192.168.0.128) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.226 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.226 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.226 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.226 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
$ sudo service iptables stop
Stopping iptables (via systemctl):                         [  OK  ]
$ ssh sun@192.168.0.128
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.128 port 22: No route to host
$ ssh sun@192.168.0.128
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.128 port 22: No route to host
$ ssh sun@192.168.0.128
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.128 port 22: No route to host
$ ssh sun@192.168.0.128
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.128 port 22: No route to host
$ ssh sun@192.168.0.128
Connection closed by 192.168.0.128
$ ssh sun@192.168.0.128
sun@192.168.0.128's password: 
Connection closed by UNKNOWN
$ ssh sun@192.168.0.128
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.128 port 22: No route to host
$ ssh sun@192.168.0.128
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.128 port 22: No route to host
```

**Follow up:**

```
-- checked cable
   -- using cable tester and other detectors 
   -- no problem found in cable 
   -- used random 10 cables

-- adapter is not broken 
   -- checked it using circuit tester by opening the system 
      (card is new so its not network adapter card problem)
   -- leds are OK showing

-- used LiveCD and did same ping test was having same problem

-- disabled ipv6 100% to make sure its not the cause

-- disabled iptables 100% so its also not the issue

-- some more info

$ nmap 192.168.0.128

Starting Nmap 5.50 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-06-08 19:11 CEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.128
Host is up (0.00045s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.168.0.128 are closed (842) or filtered (158)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.86 seconds   

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ netstat -aunt | head
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.128:58616     74.125.132.99:80        FIN_WAIT1  
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.128:56749     199.7.57.72:80          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.128:58614     74.125.132.99:80        FIN_WAIT1  
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.128:49916     173.194.65.113:443      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      1 192.168.0.128:45699     64.34.119.101:80        SYN_SENT   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.128:48404     64.34.119.12:80         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.128:54161     67.201.31.70:80         TIME_WAIT



$ sudo killall dnsmasq
  -- did not solved the problem --
  -- like many other Q/A was suggesting this same ---

$ iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination    


$ netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0


$ ssh -vvv sun@192.168.0.128
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0j-fips 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.128 [192.168.0.128] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/sun/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/sun/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/sun/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sun/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sun/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 118/256
debug2: bits set: 539/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 192.168.0.128 filename /home/sun/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 192.168.0.128 filename /home/sun/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 139
debug1: Host '192.168.0.128' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/sun/.ssh/known_hosts:139
debug2: bits set: 544/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/sun/.ssh/id_rsa (0x213db960)
debug2: key: /home/sun/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/sun/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sun/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/sun/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
sun@192.168.0.128's password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 60 padlen 4 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.0.128 ([192.168.0.128]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env ORBIT_SOCKETDIR
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME
debug3: Ignored env GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID
debug3: Ignored env IMSETTINGS_INTEGRATE_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env HARDWARE_PLATFORM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID
debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_COOKIE
debug3: Ignored env GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL
debug3: Ignored env QTDIR
debug3: Ignored env QTINC
debug3: Ignored env GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS
debug3: Ignored env IMSETTINGS_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env USERNAME
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env QT_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env XMODIFIERS = @im=none
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.utf8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env KDE_IS_PRELINKED
debug3: Ignored env GDM_LANG
debug3: Ignored env KDEDIRS
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env SSH_ASKPASS
debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env GDL_PATH
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env QTLIB
debug3: Ignored env CVS_RSH
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWPATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env G_BROKEN_FILENAMES
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Welcome to Ubuntu 11.10 (GNU/Linux 3.0.0-12-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

297 packages can be updated.
92 updates are security updates.

New release '12.04 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Last login: Fri Jun  8 07:45:15 2012 from 192.168.0.226
sun@SystemAX51:~$ ping 19<--------Lost connection again--------------
```

**Tail follow:**

-- dmesg is showing a very abnormal logs, like Ubuntu is automatically bringing the eth0 up, where eth0 is getting also auto down.

```
[ 2025.897511] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
[ 2029.347649] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
[ 2030.775556] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
[ 2038.242203] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
[ 2057.267801] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
[ 2062.871770] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
[ 2082.479712] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
[ 2285.630797] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
[ 2308.417640] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
[ 2480.948290] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
[ 2824.884798] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
[ 3030.022183] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
[ 3306.587353] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
[ 3523.566881] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
[ 3619.839585] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
[ 3682.154393] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
[ 3899.866854] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
[ 4723.978269] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
[ 4807.415682] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
[ 5101.865686] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link up
```

**How do i fix it?**

-- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1959794

```
$ apt-get install openipml openhpi-plugin-ipml
$ openipmish
> help
redisp_cmd on|off
> redisp_cmd on
redisp set
```

**Final follow up:**

Step 1: BUG for network card driver r8169

Step 2: get the latest build version

http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=4&PFid=4&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#RTL8110SC(L)

Step 3: build / make

```
$ cd /var/tmp/driver
$ tar xvfj r8169.tar.bz2
$ make clean modules && make install

$ rmmod r8169
$ depmod
$ cp src/r8169.ko /lib/modules/3.xxxx/kernel/drivers/net/r8169.ko

$ modprobe r8169
$ update-initramfs -u
$ init 6
```

Voila!!

Comment: Just to check, is the IP supplied by DHCP or is it static? Also, what role does `192.168.0.226` have in the network? (referring to `From 192.168.0.226 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All was wrong only this fixed finally: (the default driver of Ubuntu 11.10 which shifts are not correct was causing this)

```
Step 1: get it

http://152.104.125.41/search/default.aspx?keyword=RTL8111

http://152.104.125.41/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=5&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#RTL8111B/RTL8168B/RTL8111/RTL8168<br>RTL8111C/RTL8111CP/RTL8111D(L)<br>RTL8168C/RTL8111DP/RTL8111E<br>RTL8168E/RTL8111F

Step 2: cat README

# tar vjxf r8168-8.aaa.bb.tar.bz2
# ./autorun.sh  (as root or with sudo)


Step 3: lsmod | grep r8168 

note that: not 8169 was conflicting.


Works perfect now.
```

Answer (score 0):

The forum link gave one answer.  Did that work for you?

> The issue was the motherboard BMC IPMI feature. This has it own MAC
>   address that causes problems for switches with port-security.
>
> There is a dedicated LAN-port for the IPMI, but if only one cable is
>   plugged in, the IPMI will "hijack" this one and send out ocasional arp
>   requests on the same IP = problems.

Here's a general troubleshooting strategy, to add to what you have.
For completeness, can you attach output of `netstat -aunt | head`, and `sudo ufw status`?
The netstat (with just the head lines captured, you might need a few more than default) should show your ssh daemon listening (default is tcp 22). 
The ufw status should just corroborate what iptables is telling you (namely, that iptables/firewall is not interfering).

Also, do you have a host you can use to do `sudo nmap <yourboxname>` from?  This should show ssh open if it everything is functioning normally.

What devices are between the source and destination host?  Switch, router, firewall, etc..   If there is third host in your subnet, can it connect to the second?

Do you have more than one network interface on the box (wired and wireless, e.g.)?
Can you post `ifconfig` output as well?

What's upstream from you?  That is, are you directly connected into a router, switch, other switch, etc.?

Comment: Have you tried switching ports on the built-in 4-port switch?

Comment: It's hard to tell.  Can you run a non-Ubuntu liveCD from the affected system?